# Tensorflow - which is the real checkpoint file?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to used pretrained models with checkpoints but I can't figure out which file should be put into config as checkpoint. There are files:

- model.ckpt.meta
- model.ckpt.index
- model.ckpt.data0000-of-0001

I tried all of them but I see errors. In the different articles I saw just "model.ckpt" but there is no such files.

I tried to work with ssd_mobilenet from here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md

Comment: Try "model.ckpt" anyway. This doesn't identify a file, but to TensorFlow, this identifies the checkpoint path.

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work. I have a bunch of errors pretty much looking like "..MobilenetV1/Conv2d_6_depthwise/BatchNorm/gamma/RMSProp_1 not found in checkpoint"

Comment: OK. You might get more helpful answers if you provide the code that you're using to access the checkpoint.

Comment: @MattScarpino you were right, I just have to point to non-existing file including the folder with all this stuff. It doesn't make sense for me (as for this file has not been created but it works).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- model.ckpt.meta  : File to store graph information
- model.ckpt.index : File to store index of variables
- model.ckpt.data0000-of-0001 : File to store value of variables

All three files are real checkpoint files. When you restore the model using [tf.train.Saver.restore](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Saver), parameter "save_path" should be "~model.ckpt". Your error probably occurred because of the invalid save_path. Check if three files(.meta, .index, .data~) in save_path(relative path or absolute path).

Comment: Yes you are right. I actually put the wrong path. It should point to the folder/model.ckpt EVEN if there is no such file. It actually doesn't make any sense for me because this file EVEN after I finally started training has never been created.